# Swift Frames are all out of alignment

Tags: swift, frame, bounds

I am creating a game, when I navigate the menu scene to my settings scene (using a button) it all works fine.

But when i go to position say a `UISlider` on my settings scene the positioning is all out. By this i mean if i try to place it by the `self.frame.size.width/2` it is about 3/4 the way in on the screen and nowhere near the middle...

I'm sure its something wrong with the way I am progressing from scene to scene - This is my code for that

```
func settingsScene() {

    println("Settings Scene Pressed!")
    var settingscene: Settings = Settings(size: CGSizeMake(768, 1024))
    var spriteView: SKView = self.view as SKView!
    settingscene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
    var trans :SKTransition = SKTransition.doorsOpenHorizontalWithDuration(0.5)
    spriteView.presentScene(settingscene, transition: trans)
    settingsButton.removeFromSuperview()
    button.removeFromSuperview()

}
```

The above code is on my menu scene and runs when I press my "Go to settings button"

I'm sure the problem is with the `size: CGSizeMake(768,1024)` line

This is my code for the slider - I am not sure how to position is in the middle of the scene

```
    sliderDemo.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 50.0)
    sliderDemo.frame.origin = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    sliderDemo.minimumValue = 0.5
    sliderDemo.maximumValue = 5.0
    sliderDemo.continuous = true
    sliderDemo.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
    sliderDemo.value = 3.0
    sliderDemo.addTarget(self, action: "sliderValueDidChange:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
    view.addSubview(sliderDemo)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would recommend, that you don't use hardcoded sizes when initializing your SettingsScene. I would recommend that you use the size of your current scene. Something like that:

```
var settingscene: Settings = Settings(size: self.size)
```

So the different scene are always the same size.

But to solve your problem. The problem here is, that the GameViewController and the GameScene haven't the same size by default. So you have to change the sizes to match each other:

To do that, open your GameViewController and add the following line in your viewDidLoad-method after the line `scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill`, and before `skView.presentScene(scene)`:

```
    scene.size = skView.bounds.size
```

That will set the size of your scene correctly.

Comment: i tried the first amendment  - self.size and they are still bit oddly positioned. Is it the way i have positioned them on the screen? i will edit my code to show how i am placing my buttons/slider

Comment: Add the second line i've posted also to your GameViewController. That should solve your problem.

Comment: All aligned perfectly now! Brilliant answer... But one problem - The button doesn't press and the slider doesn't slide... Very weird any reason why that would happen?

Comment: Check this answer for a possible answer to your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7212692/uislider-wont-work-when-it-becomes-a-subview-of-a-uiview-other-self-view